# AppFabric crashing on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, caching, service, cache, windows-server-2008-r2

SharePoint 2013 running on Windows Server 2008 R2, updated with the latest CUs (March, April, June, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/jj891062.aspx). All O.S. updates installed.

It's a new server, I installed SharePoint today, applied the CUs and started creating the farm (single server, with the database on a separate machine).

The distributed cache service keeps crashing with these errors:

> Log Name:      Application
> Source:        .NET Runtime
> Date:          20/06/2013 17:45:32
> Event ID:      1026
> Task Category: None
> Level:         Error
> Keywords:      Classic
> User:          N/A
> Computer:      *SERVERNAME*
> Description:
> Application: DistributedCacheService.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException
>
> Log Name:      Application
> Source:        Application Error
> Date:          20/06/2013 17:45:33
> Event ID:      1000
> Task Category: (100)
> Level:         Error
> Keywords:      Classic
> User:          N/A
> Computer:     *SERVERNAME*
> Description:
> Faulting application name: DistributedCacheService.exe, version: 1.0.4632.0, time stamp: 0x4eafeccf
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b8479b
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000009e5d
> Faulting process id: 0x1160
> Faulting application start time: 0x01ce6dccc2c8252e
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\DistributedCacheService.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: 70ffbeef-d9c0-11e2-80ea-005056a002c5

Looking around, I found some posts dealing with the same issue, which seems to be caused by missing permissions:

http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/03/19/appfabric-distributed-cache-keeps-crashing-in-sharepoint-2013-fixed
http://sharepoint-blog.com/appfabric-event-id-1000-and-event-id-1026-with-sharepoint-2013

This seems indeed to be my case, as I'm using distinct service accounts with no admin privileges for the application pools.

However, as others have noted in comments to those posts, the `WindowsFabricAllowedUsers` group just isn't there, so I don't know what to do.

Any ideas?

---

### **Update 1**

**The problem is not related at all to the application pool service account. I destroyed the farm, uninstalled SharePoint from the server, re-installed it and re-created the farm, and upon accessing the Central Administration (without having configured *anything* yet), the distribute cache service still crashes with the same errors.**

---

### **Update 2**

The problem is not caused by any SharePoint CU; I tried installing only the March CU, and then I tried again using the plain RTM release of SharePoint 2013: same behaviour.

Also, [this](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2012/11/25/distributedcacheservice.exe-System.UriFormatException.aspx) doesn't help at all.

Comment: Which version of App Fabric you are using? You can get that info from Control panel - installed updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone found this in 2019, like I did, here is the solution worked for me in **SharePoint 2019**, it's magic with partitionCount change in cofiguration: [Distributed Cache service keeps crashing on start up](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43f90535-bf67-4bc6-aabe-bdda856e0292/distributed-cache-service-keeps-crashing-on-start-up?forum=SP2019)

This errors with distributed cache are often caused by permission issues. This link helped me, when changed managed account of Distributed Cache service [The AppFabric Caching Service service terminated unexpectedly](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a8532f94-c3ff-4f64-9d9f-a57a46027378/the-appfabric-caching-service-service-terminated-unexpectedly?forum=sharepointadmin), it says account should have SPDataAccess database role in sharepoint_config database.

Comment: I've not had to touch SharePoint in a while (which I'm really grateful for), but this at least makes sense. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

So I am coming to the same conclusion as above. I don't have that group either. I think I know how to solve the issue, but I am not able to test it due to permissions at the moment. The account running the service either needs login as a service rights or login as a batch job or both. Hopefully this will help someone. IF I was guessing I would say its login as a batch job. Its an IIS thing.

Comment: Not an IIS thing. AppFabric Cache is a separate OS feature, with its own permissions and security groups. Installing the feature through scripts or SharePoint runs the risk that the script will leave some details unchecked, like adding all required groups, ensuring the account has all permissions etc. Not like this hasn't happened with SP before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

- Try to reregister .net framework 4 in IIS; go to your .net directory and run Aspnet_regiis.exe with admin privileges.

and/ or

- Try to setup your machine FQDN in the host server file: find host file inside windows drivers etc directory and set up there your IP with FQDN.

Comment: Can you please add details about how to perform the two operations you mention to your post?

Comment: AppFabrid is unrelated to the framework version, IIS, or the machine's domain name.